# Can we add Register buttons to the public-facing Events Listing page?

Tags: civievent, online-registration, button

Is there a way to add **Register** buttons to the public events listing page (.../civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&html=1)?  I'd like a website visitor to be able to choose to register from this listing, rather than having to go first to the event detail page to find the **Register** button.

Using 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.2.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite it not really being best practice, but lacking programmers to work thru the API, I created a customized template directory structure as described [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/).  Then I made a copy of the ICalendar.tpl file (the default one found at **wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Page**), placed it in **wordpress/wp-content/civicrm-custom/CRM/Event/Page**, and made the modifications to show the registration links (see [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/) for how to locate your template file).  The modifications were:

- Before the table begins, add the line `{* CNP force registration links *} {assign var="registration_links" value=true;}`.  This is because the registration link code is actually already there but hidden by default (unless you use the Shopping Cart mode - then it becomes an "Add to Cart").  This sets it to show by default.
- In the table's header row, the line `{if $registration_links}<th>{ts}Register{/ts}</th>{/if}` is good as is.
- In the body of the table, I modified the existing IF as so: `{if $registration_links}<td><a {* CNP orig was href="{$event.registration_link}" *} href="{crmURL p='civicrm/event/register' q="id=`$event.event_id`"}" >{$event.registration_link_text}</a></td>{/if}`.
- I also moved that link column to be the 2nd column on the event listings page, but that's a matter of personal choice.

Afterwards, remember to add this custom template path in CiviCRM at **System Settings, Directories, Custom Template Directory** (my path was `[cms.root]/wp-content/civicrm-custom/`).

Comment: nice write up. thx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this file is  worth checking: civicrm/templates/CRM/Event/Page/DashBoard.tpl; you may want to have a customized version of the template and put something like a piece of code below  into an appropriate place of HTML markup:

`<a href="{crmURL p="civicrm/event/register" q="reset=1&id=`$id`"}" title="{ts}Register now{/ts}">{ts}Register now{/ts} </a>`

Please do not forget to follow all CiviCRM guides regarding custom templates creation.

Comment: yurg, thx very much for your reply.  I did find the template file you're talking about - problem is I'm too novice to understand where this new code should go.  Could you please elaborate a little on that?  I know I'm probably just adding another '<td>' but I'm even having trouble identifying the columns that currently show on the event listing page.  And I WILL read up on custom template creation - thx for the heads-up.

Comment: Might it actually be the ICalendar.tpl file that would need to be modified?

Comment: In the ICalendar.tpl file I recognize the columns as being the ones displayed in the event listing.  This file actually includes the line "{if $registration_links}<td><a href="{$event.registration_link}">{$event.registration_link_text}</a></td>{/if}".  I'm assuming the answer to the IF is "no", but if it were "yes" then the link would display for us??  If so, where is that variable set to "no"?

Comment: @RuthD Perfect, you're on the right track: you've got the main idea behind all of this, please keep going!